# SSAS KPI average goal expression

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, kpi

I need to create a KPI where the Goal Expression is the average of the value expression for the entire cube.

Therefore I can use the KPI to tell me if the Value is above or below the average and by how much.

At the moment all I seem to be able to see are hard-coded numbers or lookups for the goal and not one that is created at the time for all values.

would it be something like:

```
AVG([Measures].[Sales])
```

All I seem to get is the average for the level that I am currently at...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation for AVG: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/avg-mdx

So the syntax of the function is: `Avg( Set_Expression [ , Numeric_Expression ] )`

`[Measures].[Sales]` is a numeric_expression but you need to specify what set you would like to average over. I suppose if you wanted to get the average across a complete hierarchy then you could use the `MEMBERS` function to get hold of the complete set e.g.

```
AVG(
  [Geography].[State-Province].[State-Province].MEMBERS
 ,[Measures].[Sales]
)
```

Comment: hi @whytheq, thanks for your post. In your example does the double mention of what exactly denotes the hierarchy? is [Geography] the dimension, the first [State-Province] the hierarchy and the second [State-Provice] the first member?

Comment: [Geography]  is the dimension - then hierarchy - then level. If there was something like ...[Washington] tagged on the end instead of .MEMBERS then that would be the member